# How to add user matching taxonomy term value to hidden term reference field

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have mathcing taxonomy term for all users. For exmaple user Matt has taxonomy term Matt (this is made manually).

I have hidden term reference field in node. When Matt create a node then there should be chosen to hidden term reference field term value Matt - which match for user Matt.

Problem is: How to "link" user Matt to term Matt and then how to add this value automatically when user created node?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with using the hidden term?

Comment: @knowledges33ker Trying to accomplish that content is linked to term automatically so that user does not have to do it manually.

Comment: Ok, I follow that but why? Are you trying to later have a view of all content by that user? If so, you don't need taxonomy for that.